# Create UI chat like whatsapp and how to create event touch in navigation bar (iOS xamarin)

Tags: ios, xamarin, navigationbar

I would like to ask about iOS xamarin. I'm creating an application similar to whatsapp, but I ran into the following problems:

1. Creating an UI like whatsapp in navigation bar (title bar), I dragged `ImageView`/`Label` on there, but the `ImageView`/`Label` was covered by navigation bar. Just like in the picture below: [image: UI whatsapp]
2. When the navigation bar is clicked, I want to direct the user to another controller, but I don't know how to create the event touch/click in navigation bar. Could you give me some pointers on that?

Comment: This seem to be two questions. Please search first for each single question and if you don't find anything create an own thread for each. Please also show the code you have problems with (please not the whole program).

Answer (score 0):

That's do not touch on Navigation bar, its touch on Button placed on the navigation bar. long press on Title /name in WhatsApp, and you will see highlighted area-- (touch portion) - which is a button.

```
    let buttonContainer =  UIView(frame: CoreGraphics.CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 44));
    buttonContainer.backgroundColor = .clear
    let  lbltitle =  UILabel(frame: CoreGraphics.CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 44))
    lbltitle.text = "TITLE TO DISPLAY"
    buttonContainer.addSubview(lbltitle)
    let btnTitle =  UIButton(type: .custom)
    btnTitle.frame = CoreGraphics.CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 44);
    btnTitle.backgroundColor = .clear;
      buttonContainer.addSubview(btnTitle)
    btnTitle.removeTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    navigationItem.titleView = buttonContainer
```

And here is code to push the view controller on the button tap.

```
 @objc func buttonTapped()
{
    navigationController?.pushViewController(ChatVC, animated: false)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much ios_devloper for your help. i solved to issue no 1. For issue no 2, how to pushviewcontroller to other controller using btnTitle? my code for pushviewcontroller is "NavigationController.PushViewController(new ViewProfileController(base.Handle), false);", but i get error "Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: Pushing the same view controller instance more than once is not supported (<ViewPrivateController: 0x7a6acaf0>)".

Comment: i don't use buttonTapped, because i don't know how to use it. i use event TouchUpInside. My Code only:             btnTitle.TouchUpInside += (o, s) => {
                NavigationController.PushViewController(new ViewProfileController(base.Handle), false);
            };. I only want direct to ViewProfileController.

Comment: it seems your are adding TouchUoInside  multiple time..I have modified answer with code to push view controller.

Comment: @Yulia Did it help ?

Comment: There is  only one event TouchUpInside in btnTitle. Can you give me code for push view controller without segue because btnTitle create automatically by code. thank you very much..

Comment: I already updated my answer.. please check there is code to push view controller..call it in the way I did.  And it will work. I mean use Addtarget and removetarget to add action to you button.

Comment: hi, I've been following the coding, but i still get the same error is "Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: Pushing the same view controller instance more than once is not supported (<ViewPrivateController: 0x7b56c8b0>)". Error occured when i'm call pushviewcontroller..

Comment: Can you please debug and check how many time your code "  NavigationController.PushViewController" is called when you tap on button for one time?

Comment: hi ios_devloper, i solved.. Caused by Name and class in controller is same.. my code:          public void buttonTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ViewProfileController controller = this.Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("ViewProfileController") as ViewProfileController;
            NavigationController.PushViewController(controller, false);
        }.

Comment: great! Happy coding!